# C# XML comment to say 'no exceptions thrown'?

Tags: c#, exception, xml-comments

In C# XML comments, we have the [<exception> tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#exception) to say that a method throws a particular type of exception.

What is the best way to tell the library users that a method does *not* throw any (expected) exceptions? Is the absense of <exception> tags enough? Or is there a special XML tag that I missed?

Comment: I'd just use the "remarks" for this: `/// <remarks>This method does not throw any exceptions.</remarks>` (of course, you can't really guarantee that a method doesn't throw ANY exception because of things like out-of-memory and out-of-stack-space)

Comment: No special tag I can think of. An absence *could* be enough, but I would think you'd have to be very consistent about it across your code base for it to actually be meaningful. I only say that because I've only ever seen that tag be used very sporadically, personally. I would never assume a lack of that tag means no exceptions are thrown.